# asset pipeline not generating application.js application.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets, asset-pipeline

not sure what I'm doing wrong. but I get:

```
 GET http://localhost:3001/assets/application.css 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my config:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc3'              
gem 'rake', '0.9.2'                   
group :assets do
  gem 'sass'
  gem 'coffee-script'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'sprockets'
end
```

in application.rb:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

in app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

similarly for app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

Why aren't the /assets/application.[css|js] generated/accessible? do I need to run something manually? also is sprockets needed or it's part of rails now?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a specific answer to your problem, but it might solve it:  I ran into a lot of issues which were fixed by switching to rc5 - I notice in your gemfile you're using rc3.  I was getting a lot of hiccups like this when I was on rc4.

You don't need to add sprockets in your gemfile anymore once you do this either.  Also, you don't mention it but do you have gem 'jquery-rails' in your gemfile too?

Comment: I did have jquery-rails. Moving to rc5 made things better certainly. However, it still times out to fetch assets/application.js and assets/application.css and actually kills the server with: .gem/ruby/1.8/gems/tilt-1.3.2/lib/tilt/template.rb:38: [BUG] rb_gc_mark(): unknown data type 0x3a(0x105608c58) corrupted object
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
Not sure if I need ruby 1.9.2 or something else? also do I need to somehow precompile the manifest files or rails does that on startup?

Comment: Rails compiles when the server starts up so you don't need to do that... As to upgrading to ruby 1.9.2 I don't think that's your problem but I always think it's best practise to future proof yourself by working with the latest versions.  If you're comfortable enough to be using Rails 3.1 then you should definitely be moving up to Ruby 1.9.2 ...also if you're thinking about using Heroku Cedar supports both Rails 3.1 and Ruby 1.9.2 - that's what I am using

Answer (score 0):

As Richard pointed out, moving to rc5 helped:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc5'
```

but I was still getting "stack level too deep" issues which I finally figured out was due to my version of sprockets (beta.13) so I added a previous version the gem file:

```
gem 'sprockets', '2.0.0.beta.12'
```

and things are working fine :)

Comment: Where were you getting "stack level too deep"?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this problem as well and it took me a lot of tinkering to get it back to a working state.  What I finally ended up doing that worked is:

1. Adding the following line to application.rb:

   Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets) if defined?(Bundler)
2. Changing up my Gemfile so that I had the following defined:

   group :assets do

   gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"

   gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"

   gem 'uglifier'

   end
3. Bundle install, relaunch my server and voila, I have css and js again.